# Pass js variable to Jinja template in Ckan

Tags: python, jinja2, ckan

I want to pass javascript variable value to jinja2 template to query db according to some user requests.I can store user requests in js variable but I cannot pass variable value to Jinja.Do you have any idea or example?I use ckan project so I have to use Jinja template.I made some research maybe I have to use ajax request but how can I learn which function will be running in backend side as far as I know ckan use pyloans framework in backend side.How to render template in pyloans framework.Do you have any example?

Comment: Probably I will get backlash for this but I don't believe you can, the template gets rendered and that's it, then you execute your javascript.
One way of doing something similar would be using the endpoint variables: /api/endpoint/<VAR> and then passing those back to jinja, but inside the template, first WHY would you have to do this if you can modify it with javascript alone, and no I don't believe you can do it

Comment: I use treeview.When user click any node,I can get node value via jquery.But below the treeview, there is a block structure that send request backend to list datasets in same page.This structure waits node value,so  when user click any node I want to pass value block structure to immediately.

Answer (score 0):

As @E.Serra [has already pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52502405/pass-js-variable-to-jinja-template-in-ckan#comment91945654_52502405) this is not possible: the Jinja-templates are executed on the server, while the JavaScript is executed afterwards in the browser.

Hence, you can either

- compute the desired content when the page is first loaded and include it in your Jinja-template. For this, you would implement the [`ITemplateHelpers`](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/extensions/plugin-interfaces.html#ckan.plugins.interfaces.ITemplateHelpers) interface and implement a custom helper function which you can then call fro your template.
- compute the desired content asynchronously after the page has loaded. For this you would send a web request from JavaScript to a CKAN API end point. If none of the [existing API functions](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/api/index.html) provide what you need then you can add your own using the [`IActions`](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/extensions/plugin-interfaces.html#ckan.plugins.interfaces.IActions) interface.

Comment: Thank you very much.I implemented your second idea.What I want  is to list datasets according to chosen organization name.I can send ajax request after user click the node on the treeview then I can get datasets from API.But I cannot pass organization names to the line in the ninja block   '{% for package in h.get_datasets("name").results %}'

Comment: With document.getElementById I can pass organization name to <ul> element but then value of element does not run in {% for package in h.get_datasets("name").results %}

Comment: Maybe.I have to render the jinja template.But I don't know how to make in pyloans framework.Ckan uses pyloans

Comment: You cannot use the values returned by the AJAX API call in the Jinja templates -- the templates have long been executed at that point. You will need to dynamically update the DOM using JavaScript when your AJAX request completes. This has nothing to do with Pylons or Jinja.

Comment: Thank you very much.I have to use variable inside Jinja.Maybe I should find another solution.I tried ckan hierarchy-extension but it redirect another page and list datasets in that page when I click the node.If I can run this process in the same page,my problem will be solved.